# Проверка универсального типа

Tags: c#, generics, типы

Как проверить универсальный тип на соответствие другому типу?
Имеется следующие:

```
    Filter<T> C<T>()
    {
        if(T is IFilter)
            return new Filter<T>()
    }
```

Проверка `FilterType is IFilter` не выполняется.

Comment: Используйте `typeof(T)`

Comment: Использовал таким образом: `typeof(T) is IFilter`, но это выражение возвращает false. В метод C, я передаю тип наследующийся от IFilter. Документация : https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#type-testing-with-the-typeof-operator

Comment: А зачем проверка вообще, это же обобщение, используйте ограничение `Filter<T> C<T>() where T : IFilter` и всё, есть гарантия, что T реализует IFilter, никаких других проверок не нужно. https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.38.php, https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint

Comment: Славный добрый aepot ! В этом контексте это сработает, но мне нужно проверять на соответствие не только с IFilter, но и многими другими интерфейсами и абстрактными классами. Их штук 5-6. Пример упрощён

Comment: Будьте осторожны в своих желаниях. А так берете рефлексию `typeof(T).IsAssignableTo(typeof(IFilter))`, и всего делов

Comment: Паттерн матчинг первым аргументом требует значение, а не его тип, поэтому не прокатил. `typeof(T) is IFilter` возвращает `false`, потому что `true` вернет `typeof(T) is Type`, поняли подвох?

Comment: IsAssignableFrom*/IsSubclassOf , не помогли - результат false (

Comment: `IsAssignableTo` != `IsAssignableFrom` - если у вас древний фреймворк, то надо так `typeof(IFilter).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))`

Comment: Сработало) Ура-ура-ура !

Comment: @aepot, Можете ответить на вопрос, вы дали исчерпывающие наставления.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`T is IFilter` не прокатит, так как первым аргументом сопоставления шаблона должно быть значение, а не тип.

Здесь поможет рефлексия.

```
if (typeof(IFilter).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
{
    // ...
}
```